# Show default "new" page with visualforce when overriding new button?

Tags: visualforce, object, standard

Is it possible to show the standard "new" for a standard object page with visualforce? Or do you have to recreate all fields in your VF page?

Something like `<apex:detail >` just for the new button.

Comment: Then why override in the first place?

Comment: I want to dynamically update some values when a user selects a certain drop down value. Multiple values depend on these so I want to update them via JS

Comment: The simplest implementation is likely to use `Field Sets`. Does [Working with Field Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) look like it might get you what you need?

Comment: @AdrianLarson That looks good. It is definitely less work and cleaner than recreating the whole page layout with single field tags. Could you post that in an answer?

Comment: Will do shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've tried to recreate `Page Layouts` in the past using `Visualforce`, I turned to `Field Sets`. Here is the example in [Working with Field Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm)
:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Contact[f]}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```